Can't update my state when search inside the list (using cubit)
 class SelectStoreWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function onNavigate;
  SelectStoreWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.onNavigate,
  });
  final cubit = AppliesCubit();
  final controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: BlocProvider<AppliesCubit>(
            create: (context) => cubit..fetchStores(),
            child: BlocConsumer<AppliesCubit, DataState>(
                listener: listener,
                builder: (context, state) {
                  if (state is LoadingState) {
                    return const CustomLoadingWidget();
                  }

                  if (state is AppliesState) {
                    return buildBody(state);
                  }
                  return Container();
                })));
  }

  buildBody(AppliesState state) {
    return Consumer<ChooseStoreProvider>(builder: (context, ctrl, child) {
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
        
          CustomTextField(
            onChangeValue: (val) {},
            hintText: AppStrings.selectGroceryField,
            
            readOnly: true,
            suffixIcon: AppImages.arrowDown,
            onTap: () {
              ModalHelper.showStores(context, (val) {
              }, state, cubit);
            },
            onlyTap: true,
          ),
        
          ),
        ],
      );
    });
  }


}

That's my screen. That's my modal:
 static showStores(context, Function onTapYes, AppliesState state,
      AppliesCubit cubit) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => SelectStoreModal(
              onTapYes: onTapYes,
              state: state,
              cubit: cubit,
            ));
  }

And in my next screen (in my modal) I am trying to search text inside my list:
class SelectStoreModal extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function onTapYes;
  final AppliesCubit cubit;
  final AppliesState state;
  const SelectStoreModal({
    super.key,
    required this.onTapYes,
    required this.state,
    required this.cubit,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding:
          EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
      child: Container(        
          child: Consumer<ChooseStoreProvider>(builder: (context, ctrl, child) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  CustomTextField(
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: Dimens.font14,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        color: AppColors.black600),
                    onChangeValue: (value) {
                      print(value);
                     cubit.searchStores(value);
                    },
                    backgroundColor: AppColors.black100,
                    borderColor: Colors.transparent,
                    prefixIcon: AppImages.search,
                    hintText: AppStrings.search,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 24.h,
                  ),
                  ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: state.filteredStores?.length,
                      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                        final data = state.filteredStores?[i];
                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                ctrl.select(i);
                              },
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  ctrl.selectedStore == i
                                      ? SvgPicture.asset(AppImages.filledRadio)
                                      : SvgPicture.asset(AppImages.emptyRadio),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: 16.w,
                                  ),
                                  StoreComponent(
                                    data: data!,
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                           
                          ],
                        );
                      }),
                 
                ],
              ),
            );
          })),
    );
  }

  
}

 onChangeValue: (value) {
                          print(value);
                         cubit.searchStores(value);
                        },

That's where I try to do it.
and here is my cubit:
 Future<void> fetchStores() async {
    var currentState = state as AppliesState;

    emit(currentState);
    emit(LoadingState());

    var response = StoreModel.grocieries;
    currentState.stores = response;
    currentState.filteredStores = response;

    emit(SuccessState());
    emit(currentState);
  }

  Future<void> searchStores(String value) async {
    var currentState = state as AppliesState;
    
    emit(currentState);
    emit(LoadingState());

    currentState.filteredStores = currentState.stores.where((data) {
      final search = data.storeName ?? data.address;
      if (search != null) {
        return search.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase());
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }).toList();
    emit(SuccessState());
    emit(currentState);
  }

When I try to search and write any text, my list changes only when I hot reload the app, why my state is not changing? what's the reason? Maybe I emit state wrong
